# How do I make a navbars contents the same height as the Navbar?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter bootstrap and am trying to customize the Navbar.

I have a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GH9mV/2). The height of the Navbar is 75px, but the height of the contents doesn't change.

Here is my HTML in it's entirety:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<link href="dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <h4>Navbar</h4>

            <div class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, the only CSS file I am using is bootstrap.css which I downloaded from the Twitter Bootstrap homepage (using the Download Bootstrap button). The only change I have made is this:

```
.navbar {
  position: relative;
  /* Old min height
  min-height: 50px;
  */
  min-height: 75px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

I have tried changing the height of **navbar-default**, **nav** and **navbar-nav**, nothing works!

What do I need to change in bootstrap.css to have the Navbars contents match the height of the Navbar itself?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `line-height` or `padding` to have the contents fill the height of the element.

for example:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a {
    line-height: 45px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GH9mV/3/

Or:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding: 27px 15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GH9mV/5/

Both of those will do the trick, though `line-height` is an easier option to control and measure, so I would recommend it.

Notice that I've used a fairly specific selector.. This is because `line-height` and `padding` are already established on these elements in the bootstrap css, just not to the amounts you need. The specificity of my selector allows me to override those styles, or you could also track them down and edit them in the bootstrap css.

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the height of `.navbar` content, you need to increase the height on anchor tags.

Add the following in your CSS declarations:

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top    : 0;
    padding-bottom : 0;
    height      : 75px;
    line-height : 75px; /* align the line center vertically */
  }
}
```

I've used `@media` query to only apply these CSS declarations on higher resolutions.

Here is the **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/GH9mV/4/)**.

Answer (score 1):

The line-height of anchor tags is what is controlling the height of the navbar, rather than the min-height of the surrounding div.  By default, Bootstrap has this setting:

```
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Change it to this, for example:

```
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    line-height: 45px;
}
```

...and be sure to remove your alteration of the min-height.

The anchor tags, by the way, have top and bottom margins already set to 15px each.  That's why you want to set the line-height to 45px instead of 75px.  45 + 15 + 15 = 75.

Comment: I'll also add that a great way to discover which elements are filling what kind of space on a page is to right-click on an element in Firefox or Chrome and choose "Inspect Element" (or "Inspect Element with Firebug" if you have that installed).  In the developer tool area which pops up, you can mouse over the HTML in the HTML tab and see a highlighted area on the page showing the space and margins being taken up by the element tag you are hovering over.  In your case, for example, the highlighting on the div, ul, and li elements filled the full navbar, but the anchor elements didn't.